# Using wildcards in js function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function using which I am getting the auto sum for a particular field in a row.

```
$(function () {

    $('#add_iaDetails_table').on('change', '[name=days_0]', function () {
        var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
        var $rate = $row.find('input[name=rate_0]');
        var $days = $row.find('input[name=days_0]');
        var $cost = $row.find('input[name=cost_0]');
        var rate = parseFloat($rate.val());
        var days = parseFloat($days.val());
        $cost.val(rate * days);
    });
});
```

But the thing is I am appending the rows in the table dynamically and I am the name of the fields as well eg. days_1,days_2.....rate_1,rate_2....

My function here will calculate the autosum for only the first row which matches with values given in function.
Is there any way in which I can match all the appended values like days_* , rate_*
Please suggest a solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple

```
$(function () {

    $('#add_iaDetails_table').on('change', '[name=days_0]', function () {
        var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
        var $rate = $row.find('input[name*=rate_]');
        var $days = $row.find('input[name*=days_]');
        var $cost = $row.find('input[name*=cost_]');
        var rate = parseFloat($rate.val());
        var days = parseFloat($days.val());
        $cost.val(rate * days);
    });
});
```

would work where * implies that you select **any input with attribute containing the given string** or you may use the startswith selector from JQUERY where in above code you replace *** by ^**

Answer (score 1):

To accommodate dynamic content, I would be a bit more flexible with your selector; just filter on the name *starting with* `days_`, and then grab that id at the end dynamically.

Something like this:

```
$('#add_iaDetails_table').on('change', '[name^=days_]', function () {
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    var nameId = name.substr(name.indexOf('_') + 1);

    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var $rate = $row.find('input[name=rate_' + nameId + ']');
    var $days = $row.find('input[name=days_' + nameId + ']');
    var $cost = $row.find('input[name=cost_' + nameId + ']');
    var rate = parseFloat($rate.val());
    var days = parseFloat($days.val());
    $cost.val(rate * days);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [starts-with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector, like

```
$('#add_iaDetails_table').on('change', '[name^=days_]', function () {
        var uid = $(this).attr("name").split("_")[1]; //get the unique id from 'name' attribute
        var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
        var $rate = $row.find('input[name=rate_' + uid + ']');
        var $days = $row.find('input[name=days_' + uid + ']');
        var $cost = $row.find('input[name=cost_' + uid + ']');
        var rate = parseFloat($rate.val());
        var days = parseFloat($days.val());
        $cost.val(rate * days);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has a whole bunch of different selectors

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Based on your question you probably want the `Starts With` refiner

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

```
$('#add_iaDetails_table').on('change', '[name=^days_]', function () { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

The scalable/cross browser solution I can think of is, for every input element add a class that you can identify row/column index. This way you can do horizontal or vertical queries and do whatever you want.